# Select multiple columns prioritized into one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Database schema**

I have these three main tables:

1. products
2. groups
3. users

And these two pivot table:

1. product_user
2. group_user

Each user has a group.
Each product has a price which may be overriden by a price in the product_user pivot table or by a price in the group_user table.

**Problem**

Now I know how to join these tables and everything but with my current solution I am only able to select each of these prices to a separate column like price, user_price and group_price and prioritize them using PHP.

**Question**

Is it possible to select these 3 columns from these different tables and prioritize them into one column using only Sql?

So if there is a user-specific price selected this price into price, if not and there is a group-specific price selected this one and if there is no special price select the products default price.

**Laravel specific solution**

As @Shadow pointed out below, the solution is the MySQL coalesce function.

Using Laravel's query builder I was now able to achieve what I want using this statement:

```
$query->addSelect(
    DB::raw('coalesce(product_user.price, group_product.price, products.price) as price')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the coalesce() function to return the 1st non-null value from its parameters.

```
select coalesce(product_user.price, group_user.price, product.price) as price
from ...
```

Since you have not shared the exact schema with me, I cannot provide mpre specific help. I assume that there are price columns in the tables.

Comment: Never heart of this function before but it sounds very promising. And you assumed right ;)